# How to close an open port in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I need a command to list all open ports in my PC, and another command to close a port.

Any suggestions?

I need to close some applications' port.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`netstat` can be used to see the ports stat.

```
sudo netstat -lnp
```

To list all ***L**istening* ports ***N**umbers* with the ***P**rocess* responsible on each one. Terminate or kill the process to close port. (`kill`, `pkill` ...)

Without process termination, It is not possible! . See [Manually closing a port from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline). Other way you may look for a firewall solution (as isolating that port from network)

Comment: i need to close the port but without killing the application

Comment: It's possible to close a port as an external port.

Answer (score 44):

for closing open port in ubuntu you can use below command

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```

in place of `3000` you can specify your port number

`lsof` command will give information about file opened by process

**-t** : This flag specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output may be piped to kill(1). This option selects the -w option.

**-i** : This flag selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i. If no address is specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.

Comment: `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)` worked for me

Comment: something is bound to the port but not listed (even I'm using sudo). I can tell by opening the port 433 in the browser. It will say "404 page not found", but nothing's bound to that port.

Answer (score 24):

```
sudo ufw allow 22

sudo ufw deny 22
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use iptables to block the port on the network level without having to close the application. The port would still appear open, but will be unreachable.

alternatively, this is dependent on the application, some permit to disable some port ( think dovecot and the pop3 or imap port ), and some cannot. Some application can also be configured to listen only on localhost or a specific address.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `netstat -nalp` and `lsof -i:port` tools to identify process/binaries behind open port.

If you want to close port you have to kill process or stop relative service.If you want run services only for your local box you can configure respective service to listen on localhost/127.0.0.1 not on all available (0.0.0.0) ips.

Answer (score 5):

To show lists of all open ports:

```
netstat -lnp
```

To close an open port:

```
fuser -k port_no/tcp
```

example:

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

In both you can use `sudo` if needed.

Comment: For some cases the second command returns the following error: `bash: fuser: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

If your port opened due to running a service, like vsftpd for ftp service, you can stop and then disable the service so that executable file related to the service will be killed too. in debian base systems you can run bellow commands to destruct a service:

```
service SERVICENAME stop
systemctl disable SERVICENAME
```

GoodLuck

Comment: Thank you. I checked the service name by `sudo netstat -lnp` and ran your suggested commands to stop the port 22 :)