# KDE Connect: how to reverse opening ports in ufw?

Tags: kubuntu, ufw, kde-connect

OS: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS

I've managed to use KDE Connect successfully but I have a question about the `ufw` settings that are required to allow Kubuntu 16.04 to see my Android.

When I installed Kubuntu, one of the first things I did was to activate `ufw` and this is the terminal output:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
sudo password for dkbose:
Status: inactive
sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
sudo ufw default deny
Default incoming policy changed to 'deny'
(be sure to update your rules accordingly)
```

Then, to use KDE Connect, I had to open certain ports as described in https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect:

```
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
sudo ufw reload
```

My question is this: I will be using KDE Connect rather infrequently. So how can I reverse the opening of the ports each time I've finished using KDE Connect?

Based on what I read in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW, is running

```
sudo ufw delete allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw delete allow 1714:1764/tcp
```

the thing to do?

Do I also need to run

```
sudo ufw reload
```

to "update" ufw's rules?

I've seen https://askubuntu.com/a/410225/248158 but I'm not sure that answer is applicable to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can remove any rule by inserting `delete` into the command like you showed.
**No**, you don't need to reload ufw to apply rules - ufw is not a service, it "just" generates/saves/deletes proper `iptables`/`ip6tables` rules.

You can always check the results with

```
sudo iptables-save | grep 1714
sudo ip6tables-save | grep 1714
```

Btw: it might be a good idea to restrict the rules to devices on your local network (especially when you are not behind some sort of NAT-router/firewall), I also added a comment to the rules.

```
sudo ufw allow proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1714:1764 comment 'kdeconnect'
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1714:1764 comment 'kdeconnect'
sudo ufw allow proto udp from 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 to any port 1714:1764 comment 'kdeconnect'
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 to any port 1714:1764 comment 'kdeconnect'
```

You would delete those rules with

```
sudo ufw delete allow proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw delete allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw delete allow proto udp from 2a02:8389:187:7000::/64 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw delete allow proto tcp from 2a02:8389:187:7000::/64 to any port 1714:1764
```

(You can omit the comments)

Comment: Could you please extend the IPv6 bit? Maybe do we need to [use `fc00::/8`](https://serverfault.com/a/216611/407820)? Or [`fe80::/64`](https://askubuntu.com/a/887391/349837)? Also, wouldn't be preferable 192.168.0.0/16, to include other probable LAN IPs?

Comment: Adding `fe80::/64` is your LAN (link local addresses) should fix all local machines.  I don't think `192.168.0.0/16` is usefull, as you probably uses a `/24` netmask for your local network.